# How to upgrade to a specific version of PHP?

Tags: 10.04, server, upgrade, php

I have an Ubuntu 10.04 Server installation with PHP 5.3.2 installed, I want to upgrade it to PHP 5.3.5. I'm led to believe that `apt-get upgrade` will only install security updates, we're on this LTS release and don't plan on updating our servers until 12.04, so it's pretty important for us to be able to update PHP.

Any ideas?

Many thanks.

Comment: Related, possible duplicate http://askubuntu.com/questions/72387/upgrade-php-version-to-5-3-on-ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

Then you'll most likely have to build from source. Head to http://php.net, download the sources and build your PHP version.

Comment: I'll give that a go and come back with an update.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep current with the latest upstream version, you should compile PHP from source. That allows you to tweak your installation even more, take time for reading through [the extensions page](http://php.net/manual/en/extensions.alphabetical.php) for customizing PHP. Running `./configure --help` in the source folder shows you a list of options too.

When compiling from source, it's strongly recommended to subscribe to the PHP announcements mailing list. Go to http://php.net/mailing-lists.php, check the radio button "Normal" at Announcements, fill your email address in the bottom form and press "Subscribe".

Answer (score 0):

Just install it from the source. There is not expected release data for the next version in the repository.

Comment: I'll give that a go and come back with an update.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the ppa listed here: https://launchpad.net/~nginx/+archive/php5?field.series_filter=lucid

It points to ppa:nginx/php5

I haven't tried it, tho..

Answer (score 0):

I installed Zend Server Community edition to get an updated version of PHP.

http://www.zend.com/en/products/server-ce/downloads

To me, this is a relatively easy way to keep PHP up to date. Not the latest and greatest, but Zend will eventually catch up IMHO.

The most important steps, for me, was making sure that all the unwanted parts didn't launch when the server rebooted. The Zend Server daemons are controlled via: /usr/local/zend/bin/zendctl.sh which is symlinked to /etc/init.d/zend-server. These can be turned on/off using a variation of `update-rc.d zend-server defaults`

PS: If you try this, make sure you type "CE" for "Community edition" during apt-get install, otherwise it's not free (as in beer).

Answer (score 0):

Security patches will be back ported. Features will not. This the entire point of LTS. Your alternative is to build from source.

Comment: This is essentially correct, but: **(1)** Serious stability/usability bugs may also be backported, **(2)** [this policy](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/StableReleaseUpdates) is in no way specific to LTS releases (and actually, LTS releases have *exceptions*: kernels are backported, and drivers for some new hardware are backported), and **(3)** backports are often available outside of the default-enabled software sources, [through the `-backports` repositories](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBackports).