# Upgrade PHP version to 5.3 on Ubuntu

Tags: php, server

How can I do a version upgrade from 5.2 to 5.3?  php update/upgrade is saying I'm using the latest version.

I'm using Ubuntu Server 9.04

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used this tutorial http://atik97.wordpress.com/2010/06/12/how-to-upgrade-to-php-5-3-in-ubuntu-9-10/

Comment: This method didn't work for me, it's still show php 5.2.6

Answer (score 1):

This was Discussed in [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/36040/installing-php-5-3-on-ubuntu-server)

Comment: I'm on 9.04, not 8.10

Answer (score 1):

you should upgrade your ubuntu version. you can get the .deb files for new versions if you want to use apt, and pin them but you are likely to enocuter dependency problems.

please do a dist upgrade. the utility that does all the work for you in ubuntu is called update-manager-core

read up here

http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/get-ubuntu/upgrade

and here

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LucidUpgrades

Answer (score 0):

to upgrade to 5.3.10 (or any other version as they become available in the ubuntu repositories) you can also add this line

```
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted
```

to /etc/apt/sources.list

the run
apt-get update & apt-get install php5

you would probably want to remove the line from the sources.list after that, to make sure that the rest of the software stays the same.

also backup before.